# Creating a shorter version of a bash command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

i am novice to the Linux shell and had to recently start using it for work...i have now got used to the basic commands in bash to find my way around...however there are a lot of commands i find myself typing over and over again and its kind of a hassle to type them every time...so can anyone tell me how can i shorten the command syntax for ones i use frequently.

A very simple example, i use the `ls -lh` command often, though this is quite short but im just giving an example. Can I have something (a shell script may be) so that I can run it by typing just say `lh`.

I want to do it for more complex commands.

Comment: Just make sure that `lh` doesn't do something else (I don't think it does but you may run into that with other abbreviations).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
alias lh='ls -lh'
```

If you want to make this persistent across sessions, put it in your `.bashrc` file. Don't forget to run `source .bashrc` afterwards to make bash aware of the changes.

If you want to pass variables, an alias just isn't enough. You can make a function. As an example, consider the command `lsall` to list everything in a given directory (note this is just an example and thus very error prone):

```
function lsall
{
    ls $1/*
}
```

`$N`gets replaced with the Nth argument.

Comment: after you edit your .bashrc, the changes won't magically appear in your current shell -- you will have to `source .bashrc`.  New terminal windows will pick up the changes.

Answer (score 4):

You would place the following alias in your `.bashrc` file:

```
alias lh='ls -lh'
```

Now `lh` is shorthand for `ls -lh`.

For more complicated tasks you could use a bash function.  For example, on one of my machines I have a function which causes 'ls' to run after every successful 'cd':

```
cdls() {
  builtin cd "$*" && ls
}
alias cd='cdls'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define [aliases](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html).  For longer commands, use a function, put it into a library file and source it whenever you want to use your functions.

Comment: And be sure and follow the link to functions as well - sometimes an alias is just too simple.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, since you want to learn bash: you could also write a function

```
lh() {
    ls -lh "$@"
}
```

although I would never write that when a simple alias would do ;-)

Answer (score 1):

;) Heh, I remember one problem when I was starting out on Linux, which is that I would ask questions like these, and people would diligently answer them, but no one would explain how to make such changes permanent, and so I found myself typing in a bunch of commands every time I opened a terminal.

So, even though others have accurately answered this question... if you want to make the change permanent, put the alias-line into your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc file (~ = your home directory). It depends a bit on your distribution on which is run when, but I always try adding my aliases to ~/.profile first and if that doesn't work, then ~/.bashrc. One of them should work for sure.